# Domain error handler decorators in nodejs functions

Tags: jquery, node.js, error-handling, wrapper, decorator

I am trying to write a decorator for my node js function. Something like

```
'Test func a': custom_decorator( func(x)){
   ..
   ..
 ..
 })
```

Let's say I want to add domain error handler to my function, I want to abstract domain error handling to all my functions..

```
var d = domain.create().on('error', function(err) {
  console.error(...);
});

d.enter();
  "My function"
d.exit()
```

I want to move error handling to a decorator so that function writers can just call it using

```
function_name : errorDecorator(fn)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example:

```
function sum(a, b) { return a + b; }

function logDecorator(fn) {
  return function() {
    console.log(arguments);
    return fn.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}

var sumLog = logDecorator(sum);

sumLog(1, 10); // returns 11 and logs { '0': 1, '1': 10 } to the console
sumLog(5, 4); // returns 9 and logs { '0': 5, '1': 4 } to the console
```

Where:

- [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) is an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to `logDecorator`.
- [`fn.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) calls a function with a given `this` value and arguments provided as an array (or an array-like object).

**UPDATE**

Another example with a try-catch:

```
function div(a, b) { 
  if(b == 0)
    throw new Error("Can't divide by zero.");
  else
    return a / b;
}

function logDecorator(fn) {
  return function() {
    try {
      console.log(arguments);
      return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    } catch(e) {
      console.error("An error occurred: " + e);
    }
  };
}

var divLog = logDecorator(div);

divLog(5, 2); // returns 2.5 and logs { '0': 5, '1': 2 } to the console
divLog(3, 0); // returns undefined, logs { '0': 3, '1': 0 }, and "An error occurred: Error: Can't divide by zero." to the console
```

Comment: Might be helpful for deeper study [factory-constructor-pattern](http://javascript.info/tutorial/factory-constructor-pattern)

Comment: Thanks victorkohl. But how do you wrap a try-catch? (i.e) have a standard error handler wrapper for all  the functions.

Comment: Added an example with try-catch.

Comment: Thanks victorkohl. How do i add a timeout in logdecorator(fn)